# Spark Dataframe join heap space issue and too many partitions

Tags: scala, dataframe, join, apache-spark-sql, heap-memory

I am trying to join dataframes and in fact filtering in advance for simple testing. Each dataframe after filter has only 4 rows. There are 190 columns per dataframe.

I run this code in local and it runs super fast (albeit only 22 columns). Also, the partition size when I check in local is just 1. The join is pretty simple on 2 key columns and I made sure that there is no Cartesian product.

When I run this in my Dev/Uat cluster, it is taking forever and failing in between. Also, I see that the paritions created are around 40,000 per join. I am printing it using resultDf.rdd.partitions.size.

I've divided the join like this and it didn't help.

var joinCols = Seq("subjectid","componenttype")

val df1 = mainDf1.filter("metricname = 'NPV'").withColumnRenamed("my_attr","df1attr").withColumnRenamed("value","df1val")
    val df2 = mainDf2.filter("metricname = 'NPV'").withColumnRenamed("my_attr","df2attr").withColumnRenamed("value","df2val")
    val df3 = mainDf3.filter("metricname = 'NPV'").withColumnRenamed("my_attr","df3attr").withColumnRenamed("value","df3val")
    val df4 = mainDf2.filter("metricname = 'NPV'").withColumnRenamed("my_attr","df4attr").withColumnRenamed("value","df4val")

var resultDf = df1.as("dft").join(df2,joinCols,"inner").select("dft.*","df2attr","df2val")

//check partition size here and show the dataframe to make sure we are getting 4 rows only as expected. I am getting 4 rows but 40,000 partitions and takes lot of time here itself.

resultDf = resultDf.as("dfi").join(df3,joinCols,"inner").select("dfi.*","df3attr","df3val")

//Mostly by here my program comes out either with heap space error or with exception exitCode=56

resultDf = resultDf.as("dfa").join(df4,joinCols,"inner").select("dfa.*","df4attr","df4val")

The naming convention used is all dummy to put the code here. So, please don't mind with that.

Any inputs/help to put me in right direction?

Comment: Can you check the duplicate values in your join keys?

Comment: I checked...no duplicates. in fact, I took the dataframe after the first join and analyzed it manually in Excel.